# How to use RPC response extensions for debug data

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

The google protobuf [API Best Practices](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/api/#dont-include-fields) has the following to say about how to best separate debug data from normal client information:

> Returning debug data in response protos used to be a common practice,
> but we have a better way. RPC response extensions (also called “side
> channels”) let you describe your client interface with one proto and
> your debugging surface with another.

Which sounds great. The only problem is I can't find any official documentation about these "RCP response extensions" or how they should be used.

This would mostly be relevant for C++/C# implementations, but I imagine that this is a standard concept that's available everywhere.

Comment: I encourage you to go to the source. Consider raising an issue against the docs ([issues](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protocolbuffers.github.io/issues)) asking for clarification. There's a Gitter [grpc/grpc](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#grpc_grpc:gitter.im) and a Google Group [protobuf](https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf) where you may get guidance.

Comment: @Daz Yeah created a [github issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protocolbuffers.github.io/issues/83). Let's see if there's more of a response than here. One can only hope. It's rather surprising that such a major technology has things in its FAQ that apparently nobody has ever tried out.